# realpath not working on newly created files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

```
test :
    touch test
    echo $(realpath test)
    echo $(shell realpath test)
    rm test
```

When I run `make`, `$(realpath test)` returns the empty string, whereas `$(shell realpath test)` returns the exptected result. Why is this? I've tried using `.ONESHELL` but it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, shell `realpath` and the GNU make `realpath` function are different.  Shell `realpath` will return a path even if the file doesn't exist:

```
/home/me$ rm -f blahblah
/home/me$ realpath blahblah
/home/me/blahblah
```

But, GNU make's `realpath` will return the empty string if the file doesn't exist.

So, why does the file not exist?  Because make will expand *all lines* of the recipe before running *any line* of the recipe.

That means that the make functions like `$(realpath ...)` and `$(shell ...)` are expanded first, before the first line of the recipe (`touch test`) is run... and so at the time they are expanded the `test` file doesn't exist.

In general you never want to use make's `$(shell ...)` function in a recipe and you can't use make constructs to "interact" with operations that happen inside your recipe.  You should use shell functions for that:

```
test :
        touch test;
        echo $$(realpath test)
        rm test
```